# Passing self Class Type as Argument

Tags: python, class, sorting, type-hinting

I'm creating a sorting application where there is a base class, `SortingAlgorithm()`, from which other classes (one for each sort type) are derived (`BubbleSort()`, `RadixSort()`, etc).

The base class contains two functions which are relevant here: `sort()` and `presort()`. The `sort()` function performs the sort itself, and the `presort()` performs a presort (executed prior to the actual sort, to test whether there is an improvement in performance). `Presort()` can be one of two operations:

1. We iterate over all subsequent pairs in our list sequentially, and flip them if they're in the wrong order
2. Two sorting algorithms, A and B, are applied to the first and second halves of our input list, respectively.

---

**My question is that in the second operation above, we must pass two instances of classes which derive from `SortingAlgorithm`. How is this enforced, through type hints (or other)?**

My current approach is having the two sorts passed within a sequence, and check that the elements are of type `SortingAlgorithm`:

```python
import abc
from typing import Sequence

class SortingAlgorithm(abc.ABC):
    @staticmethod
    def presort(input_list: list, algorithms: Sequence[SortingAlgorithm]) -> list:
        # ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def sort(self, input_list: list) -> list:
        # ...
```

However, this throws an unresolved reference error for `SortingAlgorithm`. Passing `filename.SortingAlgorithm` throws an error regarding circular import (since I have to import the containing file).

Have gone wrong here somewhere, or is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is presort supposed to get the two classes as two parameters, or is each class's implementation of presort calls it with its own class?

Comment: ``"SortingAlgorithm"``

Comment: What @MisterMiyagi said, without emphasis on the quotes: Place `"SortingAlgorithm"` inside quotes

Comment: Thank you! Adding quotes has done the trick.

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer presort would be called like this `presort(list, [BubbleSort(), RadixSort()])` where these two sorts inherit from `SortingAlgorithm`